# Webpack исполнить скрипт и подключить

Tags: javascript, webpack

**Вопрос:** Как мне подключить исполненный скрипт при сборке и пересборке в проект?

Допустим у меня есть скрипт `merge.js`, в нем подгружаются json файлы и колдуется всякая магия.

Я могу его подключить в проект

```
let a = require('./merge')
```

Но я не хочу его исполнять на клиенте. Беру DefinePlugin

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  MERGE: JSON.stringify(require('../js/merge'))
})
```

Но тогда при изменении json файла, `--watch` не будет отрабатывать

Пробовал написать декоратор над дефайн плагином (https://webpack.js.org/api/plugins/), но json файлы грузятся только в merge.js, из-за этого не получилось нормально управлять watch

Comment: а что находится в `js/merge`? Просто не понимаю смысла в "не выполнять", как вы хотите его не выполнять если при изменении он должен исполнится?

Comment: там подгружаются json файлы с локализацией, в моем случае лучше грузить локализацию одним файлом, чем разбивать на ensure

Comment: Верно, но если вы добавите поле/свойство/условие как он без выполнения должен заменить собой старый код? При разработке можете опустить этот момент, экономить на дозагрузке файлов это ерунда.

Comment: Можете его отдельно в `entry` дописать, если не хотите чтобы он грузился из приложения

Comment: в моем случае столько скриптов грузится, что упираюсь в лимит по загрузке скриптов. И эта проблема быстра не решаема...

Comment: Вопрос: Просто не понимаю смысла в "не выполнять". 
Ответ: я просто хочу подгружать результат скрипта. Иными словами, как DefinePlugin + watch

Comment: Не вижу другого варианта, как не собрать ваш файл, который грузит другие и забивает лимит загрузки в один, чтобы он работал и брал данные внутри себя, тем более вы используете webpack. Перенести все в файл с подключением через import/require и потом подключить в `entry`, как отдельная точка входа и сборки. Самое простое, другой вариант может и есть но Define это создание статики, статика и `watch` вещи не совместимые

Comment: спасибо за предложение